# Set AlarmManager and avoid time changing by the user

Tags: android, timezone, alarmmanager

I made an AlarmManager firing daily and weekly, but when I change the time it's fire, so the user can earn coins in any time not ever 24 hours. Should I use the timer or countdown because the alarm manager/jobscheduler doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or ELAPSED_REALTIME as type when you set your alarm, like this:

`long millisToFirstCoinAward = 3600000;
initialDelay = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + millisToFirstCoinAward;
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, initialDelay, yourPeriod, yourPendingIntent);`

This way the alarm does not depend on the "wall clock" time displayed on the phone and even if the user restarts the phone the alarm and the countdown will be reset so there is no incentive for this.

Comment: its a good idea but the service running when i change the wall clock too .

Comment: are you sure it's started by the alarm? maybe the service is started by multiple objects. The elapsedRealtime() can't be changed in settings. You can log it in your service. Alternatively you can store the time when the service last run and compare that to the current realtime (however the stored time will disappear when the user clears the data)

Comment: the whole problem with me is "Change the time from Settings" , i just simply wanna fire alarm everyday in 12 am .

Comment: In that case you can't rely on the device's clock / System.currentTimeMillis() at all. You need to get an independent and accurate time reference from a trusted source like an NTP server or GPS and match it to the elapsedRealtime on device and use that match to compute the time until the next alarm to schedule it at noon exactly. Remember to take into account the timezone as well if you want the user's 12 o'clock.